# updating package catch failed error while using intel graphics installer

Tags: updates, software-installation, lubuntu, intel-graphics

I tried everything but this error persist continuously in Intel graphics installer for Linux

error occurred while updating the package cache. 
error :

```
W:GPG error: https://download.01.org saucy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Lubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Lubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Lubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Lubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I m using Lubuntu 13.10.  How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Software & Updates, you must have selected "cdrom:[Lubuntu 13.10"...] while the installer cd is not inserted. I would just uncheck the option.

[image]